# Read Large XML file using XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

I am trying to read windows update package.xml file which is roughly 65mb in size, I am trying to just grab the URL attribute using Xpath but for some odd reason my object always returns empty. Here is my code:

```
doc.Load(@".\package.xml");

string xpath= "/OfflineSyncPackage/FileLocations/FileLocation/@Url";

XmlNodeList nodeList2 = doc.SelectNodes(xpath);
```

I have also tried using XmlReader which is also not working for me:

```
string packXML = @".\package.xml";
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(packXML))
{
    while (xr.Read())
    {
        switch (xr.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                if (xr.Name == "OfflineSyncPackage")
                {
                    xr.ReadStartElement("FileLocations");
                    if (xr.Name == "FileLocations")
                    {
                        if (xr.Name == "FileLocation")
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The package.xml file can be found in package.cab which is in this file: http://download.windowsupdate.com/microsoftupdate/v6/wsusscan/wsusscn2.cab

What is the best way to do this as I do not want to load whole file into memory due to size 
Any advice is appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out finally!

```
public void ParseXML(string XMLPath)
    {
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(XMLPath);

        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if (xmlReader.Name.Equals("FileLocation") && (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element))
            {
                string url = xmlReader.GetAttribute("Url");
            }
        }

    }
```